# HEIF HEIC images in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

i am using image_picker in flutter
everything is fine when I select image JPG or JPEG, but in iphone when I try to select an image HEIF the app crashes

this is my current code

```
Future<void> _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: source);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
        _file = null;
      } else {
        print('No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo.');
      }
    });
  }
```

the problem occurs exactly in this line

```
final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: source);
```

how can I admit HEIF images or convert the images to JPG before that line, otherwise i get the crash